# Laravel Query results being dropped after collection creation & paginate bug?

Tags: php, database, laravel, collections, eloquent

This query works and returns the results I want BUT once turned into a collection or tried to being "paginated" it will return an empty result. I tried paginating a simple `DB::table('users')->paginate(5)[0]` and it works, so it doesn't come from the paginate itself I guess.

**Code**

```
$photographers_available =  Photographer::where('is_photographer', '=', '1')
          ->where(function($q)use($city_id)
              {
            $q->whereHas('studioAddress', function($q)use($city_id)
         {
              $q->where('city_id', '=', $city_id);
         })
         ->orWhereHas('user', function($q)use($city_id)  // TK could reduce to 'user.address' I think
             { 
                $q->whereHas('address', function($q)use($city_id) 
              {
                 $q->where('city_id', '=', $city_id);
              });
             });
        })
          ->whereHas('stypesPhotographer', function($q)use($stype)
          {
        $q->where('shooting_type_id', '=', $stype);
          }) 
          ->whereHas('availabilities', function ($q) use ($selected_date_time)
              {
        $q->where('unavailable_start_date', '<', $selected_date_time)
          ->where('unavailable_end_date', '>', $selected_date_time);
        }, '=', 0)
          ->whereHas('bookings', function($q)use($selected_date_time)
              {
            $q->where('booking_date', '=', $selected_date_time);
        }, '=', 0)
          ->join('stypes_4_photographer', function($join)use($stype)
          {
            $join->on('photographer_id', '=', 'photographers.id')
               ->where('shooting_type_id', '=', $stype);
          });
 $photobla = $photographers_available->first();
 echo '<pre>';print_r($photobla);
 // RETURNS RESULTS CORRECTLY
 $photoTEST = $photographers_available->get();
 echo '<pre>';print_r($photoTEST);die();
 // RETURNS $photoTEST as NULL.....
 // WHY has $photographers_available BEEN EMPTIED?????
```

**Results**

```
// $photobla result
Photographer Object
(
    [fillable:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => id
            [1] => is_photographer
            [2] => service_description
            [3] => radius_around_city_available
            [4] => tax_nbr
            [5] => user_id
            [6] => average_score
        )

    [table:protected] => photographers
    [touches:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stypesPhotographer
        )

    [connection:protected] => 
    [primaryKey:protected] => id
    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [incrementing] => 1
    [timestamps] => 1
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 677
            [is_photographer] => 1
[ETC>>>>>>>>]
         )
    [original:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 677
            [is_photographer] => 1
[ETC>>>>>>>>]
 )

    [relations:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [hidden:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [visible:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [appends:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [guarded:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => *
        )

    [dates:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [observables:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [with:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [morphClass:protected] => 
    [exists] => 1
)

// THE $photoTEST result:
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

So you can see `$photographers_available` just got emptied after the `->first()`. On top of that paginate just won't work on it even if used straight at the initial query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$photographers_available; // it is a query, consider other name

$photographers_available->first(); 
// set limit 1 on the query and return it's result

$photographers_available->get(); 
// returns the query result (remember limit 1 above..)

$photographers_available->paginate(); 
// return the query result paginated (ignoring limit 1 above)
```

And I suggest you do this (without this `first` call):

```
dd($photographers_available->get());
```

or `return` this thing, instead of `echo whataver`, since this is not the way. Outputting anything like this in the controller breaks the app flow.

---

Answering the issue you have, like in the comments: revert laravel/framework to the version you had before (in the local/dev server)

Comment: Hi @jarek, not sure I am following you on this. If I do     dd($photographers_availeble->get()); 
yes it will work. I was sequencing and outputting the first and the get to test and find the problem. But the 
dd($photographers_available->paginate(5)[0]) returns   Undefined offset: 0

Comment: You have a lot of joins there and that might be breaking `Paginator` functionality, since it has problem with joins sometimes.

Comment: thanks, it is strange because before I ran the composer update yesterday it was working.... What could I do to fix it thought?

Comment: Restore previous Laravel version by using `require: { laravel/framework: "4.2.YOUR_VER"...` in your `composer.json`

Comment: the problem is that I deployed the app so the server is running the latest version and cannot have him go back.... would there be a way around it? :0

Comment: Why can't you go back?

Comment: 4.2.6 is what I had - isn't it better to run the latest stable?